# The row must be shown same order in result set according to column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.
I have the following data:

```
ID   Value   OrderNumber
1      A         NULL
2      E          4
3      C         NULL
4      B         NULL
5      F          2
6      D         NULL
```

i want to write a query that must fetch data ordering by OrderNumber column considering OrderNumber values. The query result must be below:

```
ID      Value     OrderNumber
1         A           NULL
5         F            2  --indicates row must be second in result set. 
3         C           NULL
2         E            4  --indicates row must be fourth in result set.
4         B           NULL
6         D           NULL
```

Thanks for reading and your answers.

Comment: What order should the records be in if they have `NULL` as OrderNumber?

Comment: That records must be ordered by ID column ascending.

Comment: What happens if two records both say 'position 2'? What has been the subject of discussion in lectures?   Which features of SQL Server 2008 SQL were being covered in class?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the Order Number values are unique except NULL values.

Comment: If there are 20 results, is it possible to have a value of 35 on `OrderNumber`?

Comment: There is no ordernumber value exceeding table rows count and i want to fetch all rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried a number of different ways, but the only way I can find that produces the required results in a guaranteed way is:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,Value char(1) not null,OrderNumber int null)
insert into @T(ID,Value,OrderNumber) values
(1,'A',NULL),
(2,'E',4),
(3,'C',NULL),
(4,'B',NULL),
(5,'F',2),
(6,'D',NULL)

;With Nbrs as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as n from @t
), AvailableNbrs as (
    select n,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) as rn from Nbrs where n not in (select OrderNumber from @t where OrderNumber is not null)
), RequiredOrders as (
    select ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as rn from @t where OrderNumber is null
)
select
    *,COALESCE(OrderNumber,an.n) as FinalOrder
from
    @t t
        left join
    RequiredOrders ro
        on
            t.ID = ro.ID
        left join
    AvailableNbrs an
        on
            ro.rn = an.rn
order by COALESCE(OrderNumber,an.n)
```

Where we use a few CTEs to find `OrderNumber`s that aren't currently assigned, and to match those 1-1 with rows which have no `OrderNumber`.

Results:

```
|--------- @t --------------| |----- RequiredOrders ---------| |----- AvailableNbrs -------------------| |- COALESCE -------|
ID          Value OrderNumber ID          rn                   n                    rn                   FinalOrder
----------- ----- ----------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           A     NULL        1           1                    1                    1                    1
5           F     2           NULL        NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 2
3           C     NULL        3           2                    3                    2                    3
2           E     4           NULL        NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 4
4           B     NULL        4           3                    5                    3                    5
6           D     NULL        6           4                    6                    4                    6
```

Comment: way too complex for this question

Answer (score 1):

Found a much better solution than the accepted answer:

```
declare @t table(id int, value char, ordernumber int)

insert @t values(1,'A', null)
insert @t values(2,'E',4)
insert @t values(3,'C',NULL)
insert @t values(4,'B',NULL)
insert @t values(5,'F',2)
insert @t values(6,'D',NULL)

;with a as
(
select *, row_number() over (order by id)+.1 rn1 from @t
where ordernumber is null
union all
select *, ordernumber - rank() over (order by ordernumber)+1 rn1 from @t
where ordernumber is not null
)
select * from a order by rn1, ordernumber
```

Comment: If I change ID 2s `OrderNumber` to 3 (from 4), then both ID 2 and 5 get assigned `rn1` values of 2 - so no guarantee of output order between them.

Comment: that works as well. i could understand Damien's solution. But i havent figured out your solution yet. So i prefer Damien's solution as accepted answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk i understand your solution. But i couldnt figure out "ordernumber - rank() over(order by number)+1". if you clarify a bit , it will be good for me.

Comment: @bselvan the ranking is exactly the same as row_number() in this case. The reason i used rank was that i started out with another solution and never changed it, since it did the same. I am subtracting it to find the number of lower ranking ordernumbers to find the exact position in the order, when they get the same value, it is because they are ranked side by side and the ordernumber determine the position.

Comment: thanks for explanation. i finally understand the query. This solution is quite clever. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     tableName
Order BY  CASE WHEN OrderNumber IS NULL THEN ID ELSE OrderNumber END
```

Comment: From the sample set, `ID` 4 and `OrderNumber` 4 will have the same value for your `CASE` expression, and so may appear in either order.